# Windows 10: Set Login Screen Image from Command Line

Tags: windows, authentication

Is it possible to set the Windows 10 Login Screen Image from the command line? Using a registry hack is fine.

I had though that the image would be part of a saved theme, but it appears not.

Eventually, I would like to set the image from a batch file as part of a setup for training machines.

Answer (score 0):

To set the LockScreen go to the registry and add this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization
```

Add a string with name `LockScreenImage` and the path and filename as value.